# In ios how to perform a method with NSData return type in background

Tags: ios, objective-c, performselector

In iOS how to perform a method with `NSData` return type in background.

I have tried this:

```
NSData *loginiddata=[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(loaddatawithurl:param:) withObject:OBJ];
```

but its not working.

Comment: What means "it is not working"? Provide more info about a problem.

Comment: What could it mean to perform the selector in the background but not proceed until you have the data it would return? Your thinking is confused.

Comment: I want to execute "-(NSData *)loaddatawithurl:(NSArray *)Array;" this methode in background do you have any idea how to do it? I hv tried above line of code but as performSelectorInBackground method has void return type its giving me an error of incompatible return type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems with `performSelectorInBackground` in your case:
That method has no return value
(compare Ken Thomases' comment above), and it works only with methods taking a *single*
argument. The easiest solution (in my opinion) is to use GCD (Grand Central Dispatch)
methods instead:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    NSData *loginiddata = [self loaddatawithurl:url params:params];
    // ... 
});
```

Comment: Thanks Martin R,its helpful.